# Which is the correct translation of "Two rivers cannot flow into each other."

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

- $R(x)$ - "x is a river"
- $L(x)$ - "x is a lake"
- $S(x)$ - "x is a sea"
- $F(x, y)$ - "x flows into y"

The domain consists only of waterbodies (rivers, lakes and seas).

"Two rivers cannot flow into each other."

(1) $ \forall x \forall y (R(x) \wedge R(y) \rightarrow \neg F(x, y) \wedge \neg F(y, x))$
(2) $ \forall x \forall y (R(x) \wedge R(y) \rightarrow \neg (F(x, y) \wedge F(y, x)))$

I believe the answer to be number 1, but number 2 is proposed to be the correct answer.

Is the natural language sentence ambiguous and can be translated in either way?

Comment: number $1$ says no river flows into another

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Is that not what the sentence means?

Comment: I thought the sentence means A cannot flow into B at the same time B flows into A, but A could flow into B as long as B is not flowing into A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, "two rivers cannot flow into each other" means that river A could flow into river B, or river B could flow into river A, but not both.  That is what the symbolic expression (2) means.  The symbolic expression (1) means that no river can flow into another (A cannot flow into B, and B cannot flow into A).

Comment: I can see that, my question is now whether the sentence is ambiguous and can be read as I put in (1) as well, or perhaps a third option.

Comment: Why wouldn't you say merely "a river cannot flow into another" if that were the case?

Comment: Hmm, I can see my mistake clearly now. That is what I incorrectly interpreted the sentence to mean. I could say we are messaging each other. Sorry, this has turned more into an English question but thank you.